# 419 Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again. custom login isnt working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have created a login page but I cant get past it because it says Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again.
This is my controller...

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use DB;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

 class loginController extends Controller
  {
    /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function index()
     {
            $request = Request::all();

        $registers = registers::where('employeeID', $request['employeeID'])
        ->first();

        $validCredentials = Hash::check($request['password'], $request- 
        >get('password'));

        if ($validCredentials) {
            Session::flash('login','login Successful!');
            return view('dashboard');
        }
    }
```

this is my route...

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('register');
});


Route::resource('register', 'registerController');

Route::get('login',function(){

return view('login');
});

Route::resource('login', 'loginController');
Route::resource('login', 'loginController@index');

Route::get('dashboard',function(){

return view('dashboard');
});
```

I dont have a  model because I dont think it is necessary
Though your input will be highly appreciated as I am new to laravel

Comment: You're saving a message to `Session::flash()` (which has a short lifetime), but nothing long-term. Use Laravel's built in [authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication), it will save you some headaches.

Comment: Code concept, please only use tags that are related to your problem.  phpmyadmin is a GUI for accessing mysql databases.

Comment: the flash session is used to display a success message once the login is successfull

Answer (score 0):

When trying to authenticate user in laravel use the following syntax (you can modify it to what field do you want it to check). What this code does is it will check with your database then if it's a successful attempt, then it will create User session.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
     // redirect or do anything else
}
```

for more detail you can check here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authenticating-users

=================================

I will try to exmplain your current syntax (part of it)

```
$validCredentials = Hash::check($request['password'], $request->get('password'));

if ($validCredentials) {
   Session::flash('login','login Successful!');
}
```

here's my short explaination about your code :

```
$validCredentials.............
```

only checks if the password is correct with the hash, doesn't make any sessions or cookies. which doesn't truly authenticate the user. it only checks if the password is true

```
if ($validCredentials) {
   Session::flash('login','login Successful!');
}
```

it only flash session. what you must understand is that flash session is only short term (only available on the next page and will went away if the user change page / refresh the page).

And flash session ONLY WORKS if you create long-term Session (user is trully logged in) using the code like what I wrote above

Comment: do you think my route is OK? Because I have changed edited my controller as per your suggestion and I am still getting the same error..."Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again."